# Observable gets old data

Tags: rxjs

I have a function that calls another function and subscribes to an observable:

```js
public createUserAndSession(): void {
  this.sessionService.createSession(this.form)

  this.session$ = this.sessionService.session$.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

The `createSession()` function does a Prisma mutation to create a session and calls the `setSession()` function when ready:

```js
public createSession(form: FormGroup): void {
  this.apollo.mutate<CreateSession>({
    mutation: CREATE_SESSION,
    variables: {
      name: form.controls['sessionName'].value
    }
  }).subscribe({
    next: ({data}) => {
      this.setSession(data!.createSession)
    },
    error: (e) => console.log(e),
  });
}
```

The `setSession()` function pushes the created session into a `BehaviorSubject`:

```js
private sessionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Session | null>(null);
public session$ = this.sessionSubject.asObservable();

public setSession(session: Session): void {
  this.sessionSubject.next(session)
}
```

This kind of works, I can create sessions. But when I create a new session `session$` observable gets a lot of data.

This is the console log the first time I create a session:
[image]

This is the console log the second time I create a session:
[image]

This is the console log the third time I create a session:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a subscription each time you subscribe. You need to manage the subscription.

```
private sub: Subscription;

public createSession(form: FormGroup): void {
  const obs$ = this.apollo.mutate<CreateSession>({
    mutation: CREATE_SESSION,
    variables: {
      name: form.controls['sessionName'].value
    }
  });
  if (!this.sub) {
     this.sub = obs$.subscribe({
      next: ({data}) => {
        this.setSession(data!.createSession)
      },
      error: (e) => console.log(e),
    });
  }
}
```

Then you need to call `this.sub?.unsubscribe()` when you are finished in the end of lifecycle event handler such as ngOnDestroy if it is Angular.

I am not familiar with how the apollo client works but there might be a way to watch that observable before you call mutate with something like.

```
private sub = this.apollo.watch<CreateSession>().subscribe({
  next: ({data}) => {
    this.setSession(data!.createSession)
  },
  error: (e) => console.log(e),
});
```

You will need to check the apollo documentation.