# BehaviorSubject sends old data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a component and a service:

```js
export class CreateSessionComponent {
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}

  public createUserAndSession(): void {
    this.sessionService.createSession();

    this.sessionService.session$.subscribe({
      next: (data) => console.log(data),
    });
  }
}
```

```js
export class SessionService {
  private sessionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any | null>(null);
  public session$ = this.sessionSubject.asObservable();

  public createSession(): void {
    this.sessionSubject.next('something');
  }
}
```

When the `createUserAndSession()` function is called it calls the `createSession()` function in the service which creates a record in the back-end and then adds a string (this could be the name of a session) to the `behaviorSubject`.

In the component I subscribe to the `session$` observable and here I want the value that was added by the service. But I also get old data.

The expected data should only be the last value i push into the observable.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-qwm6mg

Comment: The subject _is_ only emitting the latest data, it only replays the last value. It's the multiple subscriptions [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75609948/3001761): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-acbftz?file=src/app/session/create-session/create-session.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to filter the null value:

```
this.sessionService.session$
    .pipe(filter(data => !!data))
    .subscribe({
       next: (data) => console.log(data),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new subscription on every button click here. Instead you can do the subscription once in `ngOnInit` like below, because `subscribe` will keep emitting the new incoming values on it's own and you don't have to create a subscription every time the value in the subject changes.

```
export class CreateSessionComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.session$.subscribe({
      next: (data) => console.log(data),
    });
  }

  public createUserAndSession(): void {
    this.sessionService.createSession();
  }
}
```